# OpenSC and Firefox on Windows

Tags: firefox, smartcard, opensc

I have OpenSC and Firefox on Windows. I need to permanently unload OpenSC module from Firefox as it causes problems. I can unload it from Settings\Privacy & Security\Security\Certificates\Security devices. However next time I ran Firefox module is there again.
How can I permanently unload OpenSC module? I have found a few solutions to prevent Firefox from loading OpenSC, but they are for Linux. I use Windows.

Comment: We would really like to understand your problem. Can you go to https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/issues and open a "New issue"  Please add the versions of FireFox and OpenSC, what card you are using and do you need the command line tools of OpenSC.

Comment: This also sounds like: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/issues/2446  which was fixed in https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/pull/2459 and available in OpenSC 0.24.0